# pyglet.media.codecs.wave.WAVEFormatException: file does not start with RIFF id

Tags: python, pyglet

it says something about not having a wave format .wav do work but i need videos to work and open cv is not a option

ive tryed adding avbin64 to all the recemended files like system system64WOW resours file ext. ive tryed turning the .mp4 into .avi tryed a differnd video

```
import pyglet

pyglet.resource.path = ['C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\PycharmProjects\\project1 \\res']
pyglet.resource.reindex()

vid = ('file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4')
vidpath = pyglet.resource.media(vid)
window = pyglet.window.Window()
player = pyglet.media.Player()
source = pyglet.media.StreamingSource()
MediaLoad = pyglet.media.load(vidPath)

#player.queue(MediaLoad)
#player.play()



@window.event
def on_draw():
  window.clear()
  if player.source and player.source.video_format:
      player.get_texture().blit(50,50)
       player.draw()

  pyglet.app.run()
```

error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gebruiker/PycharmProjects/project1/venv/test", line 7, in <module>
    vidpath = pyglet.resource.media(vid)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 678, in media
    return media.load(path, streaming=streaming)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 133, in load
    loaded_source = decoder.decode(file, filename, streaming)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs\wave.py", line 109, in decode
    return WaveSource(filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\codecs\wave.py", line 61, in __init__
    raise WAVEFormatException(e)
pyglet.media.codecs.wave.WAVEFormatException: file does not start with RIFF id
```

hoped that the video would play

Answer (score 0):

> pyglet.media.codecs.wave.WAVEFormatException: file does not start with
>   RIFF id

This error occurred because you are using version **1.4.4** of pyglet. You can solve this issue by downgrading to version **1.3.2**

```
pip install pyglet==1.3.2
```